# Experience with Oracle Workspace Manager

Tags: oracle

We are exploring and experimenting with using Oracle Workspace Manager specifically for the workspace support, and for capturing historical data. I have been searching the web, and have noticed not a lot of content related to actual usage, mostly just stuff from Oracle and Oracle support sites. On stackoverflow I see several comments stating that it is not a product suited for production use or in use for serious projects, but these comments are 2010 or earlier. So, I am wondering if there is anyone here that has used it for a serious project.

Our use case is to support tracking of budget revisions, and scenario creation in a budgeting and planning system.

Thanks

Chris